# how to resolve this system of differential equations of order 1?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\dot{p}_1 & = & \frac{1}{z}p_2p_3\\\dot{p}_2 & = & -\frac{1}{z}p_1p_3\\\dot{p}_3 & = & (\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x})p_1p_2\end{array}\right.$
where $p_1(0)=a,p_2(0)=b,p_3(0)=c$ and $x,y,z$ are constants.

1) how to resolve this system differential equations by hand(not computer)? the fomulas, the calculations...

2) what if $x=y=M$ where $M$ is a constant(has no special means)?

Comment: What is the definition of $M$?

Comment: If $x = y, p_3' = 0 \rightarrow p_3 = constant$, so easy to find solution. Part a., these are nonlinear equations.

Comment: $M$ is just a constant, nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $1/z=A$ and $1/y-1/x=B$. Multipliying the first equation by $p_1$, the second by $p_2$ and adding we get
$$
p_1\dot p_1+p_2\dot p_2=0\implies p_1^2+p_2^2=\text{constant}=a^2+b^2.
$$
Multipliying the first equation by $-B\,p_1$, the third by $A\,p_3$ and adding we get
$$
-B\,p_1\dot p_1+A\,p_3\dot p_3=0\implies -B\,p_1^2+A\,p_3^2=\text{constant}=-B\,a^2+A\,c^2.
$$
We have obtained two first intergrals. We can solve for $p_2$ and $p_3$ in terms of $p_1$ and obtain a first order differential equation for $p_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did as you said but didn't have the results.  This is my try:

Comment: This is my try:
$$p^2_2=-p^2_1+a^2+b^2\\p^2_3=\frac{B}{A}p^2_1-\frac{B}{A}a^2+c^2$$
for example $p_2$:
$$p_2=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2-p^2_1}$$
$$\dot{p}_2=\pm\frac{p_1\dot{p}_1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-p^2_1}}$$
$$-p_1p_3=\pm\frac{p_1p_2p_3}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-p^2_1}}$$
but how to continue?

Comment: Substitute $p_2$ and $p_3$ in the first equation to get $$\dot p_1=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-p_1^2}\sqrt{\frac{A}{B}p_1^2-\frac{A}{B}a^2+c^2}.$$

Comment: I get
$$\dot{p}_1=\pm\sqrt{-ABp^4_1+(ABb^2-A^2c^2)p^2_1+(a^2+b^2)(A^2c^2-ABa^2)}$$
the equation under $\sqrt{\quad}$ can't be factorized with clear and simple factors. So I don't know how to resolve this differential equation with radical sign. Could you please present your idea? Thank you.

Comment: It is in separated variables. Call $F(p_1)$ the right hand side. The solution is $$\int\frac{dp_1}{F(p_1)}=C.$$ The integral might not be easy.